# Selenium PHPUnit - Check which browsers are installed on the local machine?

Tags: php, selenium, cross-browser, phpunit

I'm currently running my Selenium through PHPUnit. The project I'm working on has multiple developers and machines which the project is being developed on. What I would like to do is have Selenium/PHPUnit set the browsers being used for the Selenium tests based on what browsers are installed on the local machine the test is being run on. In other words, when on Windows, IE will be tested. While on Ubuntu, IE will not be tested (unless the user has it installed for some reason). Is there some clean way of doing this using what's already setup in Selenium or PHPUnit? Or would I have to build some sketchy workaround? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium doesn't do this automatically. If you tell it to run firefox and firefox isnt installed you'll just get a stacktrace. Try a workaround instead, or just configure your boxes manually

*EDIT*
Try checking out http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php

```
//Pseudocode
OS = php_uname (["s"])
    if (OS == 'Ubuntu'){
       run Chrome
       run Firefox
    }elseif(OS == 'Mac'){
       run Safari
    }
```

Comment: I don't really want to base it off of the operating system because that doesn't guarantee which operating system is being used. However, I'm guessing you're right about there not being a built in way to do this. So the solutions you have given are probably the best I can get. Thanks!

Comment: you'll probably have to configure your test runs manually per box if you don't want to do something hacky then